# discordjs Letting only a certian role do a certain command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm getting an error when i run this code:

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const guildMember = message.member;
    let role = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Verified");
    let role2 = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Unverified");

    if(guildMember.roles.has(role2)) {
        guildMember.setRoles(role)
        message.reply("BY THE POWER OF DISCORD... YOU ARE NOW...\n***VERIFIED*** \nUse husky?verify TO VERIFY!")
        message.channel.send("@everyone TYPE `?verify` TO VERIFY YOUR SELF AND GET ACCESS TO GENERAL AND LOTS MORE!")
    } else {
        message.reply("Sorry, you're already verified!")
    }
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "verify"
}
```

Any ideas what i did wrong?

Comment: Which error? You realize that the error *itself* tells you wahts wrong with the code ... ?

Comment: it doesnt. Thats the problem or I wouldn't be asking right now.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace to your question please?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What you defined the `hasRole()` function as? Btw. I would await your `addRole()` and `removeRole()` functions because otherwise you can't know if the role has really been removed/set to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For anyone else trying a verify command or finding roles, here ya go.

```
    if (guildMember.roles.has(role2.id)) {
        guildMember.addRole(role)
        guildMember.removeRole(role2)
        message.reply("BY THE POWER OF DISCORD... YOU ARE NOW...\n***VERIFIED*** \nUse husky?verify TO VERIFY!")
        message.channel.send("TYPE `?verify` TO VERIFY YOUR SELF AND GET ACCESS TO GENERAL AND LOTS MORE!")
    }

    if (guildMember.roles.has(role.id)) {
        message.reply("Sorry, you're already verified!")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake was, that you checked if the **guildMember** has the role "**Unverified**", I changed this to the ID of the role "**Verified**". Then you used a function named `setRoles()` although you **didn't define it in previous code** and it isn't a function of **discord.js** too so I think you wanted to add a role to the **guildMember**. I changed your `setRoles()` function to `addRole()`. Then I added a new function to remove the "**Unverified**" role with the function removeRole().

**Try to use the following code:**

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const guildMember = message.member;
    const role = message.guild.roles.find('name', 'Verified');
    const role2 = message.guild.roles.find('name', 'Unverified');

    if (guildMember.roles.has(role.id)) {
        await guildMember.addRole(role);
        await guildMember.removeRole(role2);

        await message.reply('BY THE POWER OF DISCORD... YOU ARE NOW...\n***VERIFIED*** \nUse husky?verify TO VERIFY!');
        message.channel.send('@everyone TYPE `?verify` TO VERIFY YOUR SELF AND GET ACCESS TO GENERAL AND LOTS MORE!');
    } else {
        message.reply("Sorry, you're already verified!");
    }
};
```